# Formatting in Raku

Tags: printf, raku, rakudo

I have written a function that outputs a `double`, upto 25 decimal
places. I am trying to print it as a formatted output from Raku.

However, the output is incorrect and truncated.

See MWE:

```perl
my $var = 0.8144262510988963255087469;
say sprintf("The variable value is: %.25f", $var)
```

The above code gives `The variable value is: 0.8144262510988963000000000` which is not what is expected.

Also, this seems weird:

```perl
my $var = 0.8144262510988963255087469;

say $var.Str.chars; # 29 wrong, expected 27
```

I tested the same in `C`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
   double var = 0.8144262510988963255087469;
   printf("The variable value is: %.25lf \n", var);

   return 0;
}
```

However, it works fine. Given the identical nature of `sprintf` and `printf`, I expected this `C` example to work in Raku too. Seems like `%lf` is [not supported](https://docs.raku.org/routine/sprintf).

So is there a workaround to fix this?

Comment: Note that [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) double-precision values are accurate to no more than 15 decimals.

Answer (score 6):

I think this is actually a bug in how `Rat` literals are created.  Or at least as WAT :-).

I actually sort of expect `0.8144262510988963255087469` to either give a compile time warning, or create a `Num`, as it exceeds the standard precision of a `Rat`:

```
raku -e 'say 0.8144262510988963255087469'
0.814426251098896400086204416
```

Note that these are *not* the same.

There is fortunately an easy workaround, by creating a [`FatRat`](https://docs.raku.org/type/FatRat)

```
$ raku -e 'say 0.8144262510988963255087469.FatRat'
0.8144262510988963255087469
```

FWIW, I think this is worthy of [creating an issue](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/new)

Comment: Can you say a bit more about what it means to "exceed the standard precision of a `Rat`"?  What especially confuses me here is that the precision seems to be _present_ but not printed: `say 0.8144262510988963255087469.raku` prints `<8144262510988963255087469/10000000000000000000000000>`

Comment: @codesections Imo understanding *why* "output routines like `say` or `put` do not try very hard" to display numbers with the precision someone might expect (to (ab)use a suitable phrase from the Numerics page) would best include taking on board related issues in [the Rakudo issue queue](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues) (and probably [the old Raku issue queue](https://github.com/raku/old-issue-tracker/issues/) too; important unresolved info in old issues has not yet made it to the new queue). Fwiw I'm working on reviewing/reporting related issues as part of another answer to this Q.

Comment: @raiph I have indeed read the Numerics page :)  In fact, that page (more specifically, the [Degradation to Num](https://docs.raku.org/language/numerics#Degradation_to_Num) section) is what has me so confused.  From that page, I would expect that, with `my $var = 0.8144262510988963255087469`, printing `$var` would degrade `$var` to a `Num` and thus that `say $var` and `say `$var.Num` would print the same string.  But, in reality, they don't.  (Both output strings start with `0.814426251098896`, but the `Rat` ends with `400086204416` while the `Num` ends with `3` – neither of which is correct.)

Comment: @codesections indeed, it does not seem to have run out of precision.  But how is it then that `.FatRat` *does* work?

Comment: Hmmm... I wonder if we couldn't simplify the rendering of `Rat` / `FatRat` to basically stringifying the numerator if the denominator is a power of 10?

Comment: @ElizabethMattijsen After a bit more thought, I now think that it _has_ exceeded the allowable precision (`10000000000000000000000000 > 2⁶⁴ - 1`, after all).  But the coercion to `Num` doesn't happen when `$var` is declared – only on the [first mathematical operation with the `Rat`](https://docs.raku.org/language/numerics#Degradation_to_Num) (which I guess happens in the `say` call).  The `FatRat` works because it prevents that degradation during `say`.  But that doesn't explain why `say $var` and `say $var.Num` print different strings.  Odd rounding issues inside `say`?

Comment: @codesections I think the problem is really that the `Rat` literal is created incorrectly.  Because if done at runtime, it becomes a `Num`: `'my $a = 8144262510988963255087469; my $b = $a/10000000000000000000000000; dd $b.^name;  # "Num"`

Comment: Hi. Having written comments I hoped would encourage folk to read issues, I stepped away to eat something. Now I return and boom! :) Fwiw, afaict everything both of you have just discussed (in comments above) repeat points made in the issues I mentioned (and in discussions linked to from those issues) and *ignore* what was said in those issues and discussions in response to those points.

Comment: @codesections Otoh, I never arrived at sufficient clarity to be confident about any particular tweak of what Z wrote in that page. Perhaps this time, as we focus once more on the same set of issues that have been thoroughly explored for decades in the Perl and Raku communities, we can collectively get to some suitable doc tweaks, and *perhaps* some Raku(do) tweaks? At least, that's what I'm hoping.

Comment: @codesections I'm currently reviewing the ton of Raku related mailing list discussions, design doc sections, IRC discussions, perlmonks exchanges, blog posts, issues from Raku(do) queues, and so on that swirl around this stuff, and which I've previously spent many hours trying to get to grips with. As examples of the latter, consider [sprintf `%f` bogus rounding](https://github.com/Raku/old-issue-tracker/issues/5519), [printf doesn't honor `%f` widths](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/3733), [printf, sprintf cannot handle %lf](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/1514).

Comment: @ElizabethMattijsen Ok `FatRat` can hold that much of precision. Now how can I make `sprintf` show correct value of the variable in the formatted output? Found an old issue as explored by @raiph https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/1514. It appears that it's not possible at present.

Answer (score 3):

From your question:

*I have written a function that outputs a double, upto 25 decimal places.*

From google:

*Double precision numbers are accurate up to sixteen decimal places*

From the raku [docs](https://docs.raku.org/language/numerics#Rat) :

*When constructing a Rat (i.e. when it is not a result of some mathematical expression), however, a larger denominator can be used*

so if you go

```
my $v = 0.8144262510988963255087469; 
say $v.raku;
#<8144262510988963255087469/10000000000000000000000000>
```

it works.

However, do a mathematical expression such as

```
my $b = $a/10000000000000000000000000;
```

and you get the Rat => Num degradation applied unless you explicitly declare FatRats. I visualise this as the math operation placing the result in a Num register in the CPU.

The docs also mention that .say and .put may be less faithful than .raku, presumably because they use math operations (or coercion) internally.

Sorry to be the bearer of bad news, but 10**25 > 2 **64, but what you report as an issue is correct & (fairly) well documented behaviour given the constraints of double precision IEEE P754.

Comment: Upvoted but/also: ❶ [op means] "`Rat` => `Num` degradation applied unless ..." See [Introducing `$*RAT-OVERFLOW`](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/pull/4299). ❷ "`.say` and `.put` may be less faithful than `.raku`, presumably because they use math operations (or coercion) internally" `say` uses `gist`. See [what does gist mean?](https://www.google.com/search?q=what+does+gist+mean). `put` uses `.Str`. This isn't a gist, but is still approximate for `Num`s. (Rationale is `Num`s are themselves approximate.) ❸ "correct & (fairly) well documented ... given constraints" I wish it was that simple! :)

Comment: @p6steve Thanks for the info. I was implementing brute-force [kendall-tau coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall_rank_correlation_coefficient) in `C` (to later call from `Raku`), run [here](https://glot.io/snippets/g65qhxjb94). I tested the same example in [`R` language](https://www.mycompiler.io/view/3xC6rW8) to see the accuracy of the output from my `C`. The output in my `C` example matched up to 22 places with `R` output, and thought even `Raku` would display that. As per IEEE P754, `kendal_tau_cor` output in `C` should have degraded beyond 16 digits.